# Adding headers in browser.get() requests in protractor

Tags: angularjs, testing, selenium, protractor, angularjs-e2e

i want to add cookies in headers for automatic authorization in test with protractor, but there is no native way to do this, how i understand...
How can i add custom headers to browser.get() request ?

Comment: There is no way of doing it right now. Since protractor is meant to imitate users, it might be better if you just add a step before your tests (i.e. onPrepare) to login as a user would.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium (WebDriver) does not support this. One way of solving this is by using a intermediate proxy and manipulating the headers along the line. Keep in mind that this solution works perfectly fine for HTTP, but will will require some additional workarounds if you are using HTTPS (and in most cases isn't viable).